# How do I make apache to listen to more than 2 ports?

Tags: apache-2.2

How do I make apache to listen to more than 2 ports?

Answer (score 7):

## Put more than 2 Listen directives

Put more than 2 Listen directives.

Comment: +1 for me taking a couple seconds to get it ;-)